# Scala pattern matching with mixins

Tags: scala

I wanted to enhance pattern matching based on mixin technique
for example :

```
trait Base {
  def match(x:Any):String
}

trait HandleAString {
  def match(x:Any):String = x match {
     case "A" => "matched A string"
  }
}

trait HandleOneInt {
  def match(x:Any):String = x match {
     case x:Int if (x==1) => "matched 1 int"
  } 
}


//main 
val handler = new Base extends HandleOneInt with HandleAString 
println(handler.match("a") ) //should print  "matched A string"
println(handler.match(1) )  //should print  "matched 1 int"
println(handler.match(2) )  //should throw exception
```

if you have any other technique i would like to hear about that ...

Comment: Your question is not clear to me: Are you asking about how to get your code to work, or do you ask for a different technique that does not use mixins? Also: What's the purpose of this specialized matching? Do you want to be able to pass around a matcher as an object, or do you need to match against something that cannot easily be expressed using Scala's `match` expression? In this example, it would be more reasonable to just call `whatver match {case "a" => ... case 1 => ... }`

Comment: What is exactly the question? Note that `match` is a reserved keyword, so you would need to call your method `Match` or `_match`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Honestly the mixin side smells of over-abstraction - I'd urge you to think carefully about what you actually want to achieve, and look for a simpler way of doing it. I can't help with the mixin aspect, but you can store a single match case as a `PartialFunction` and combine several using `orElse`, which may do what you want or at least point you in the direction you want to go:

```
val handler1: PartialFunction[Any, String] = {
  case "A" => "matched A string"
}
val handler2: PartialFunction[Any, String] = {
  case x:Int if (x==1) => "matched 1 int"
}

val manyHandlers = List(handler1, handler2)
val handler = manyHandlers.reduce(_.orElse(_))

println(handler("A") ) // "a" won't match, match is exact
println(handler(1) )
println(handler(2) )
```